# Can't enable codeception tests for Yii2

Tags: selenium, testing, yii2, codeception

I have problems configuring Codeception acceptance tests for my Yii2 website.

Tests are running okay, but I'd like to change the configuration so testing contact form won't send any emails. It should be pretty simple task, but I can't force it to use alternative config.

Following this tutorial: http://codeception.com/for/yii

**/codeception.yml:**

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    memory_limit: 1024M
    colors: true
modules:
    config:
        Yii2:
            configFile: 'config/test.php'
```

**/tests/acceptance.suite.yml**

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://localhost/mypage
            browser: firefox
        - Yii2:
            part: orm
            entryScript: index.php
            cleanup: false
            configFile: test.php
```

And again I have no idea which directory this file points to. I tried with /config/test.php, /tests/config/test.php, nothing.

**/config/test.php**

```
<?php
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');
$dbParams = require(__DIR__ . '/test_db.php');

/**
 * Application configuration shared by all test types
 */
return [
    'id' => 'basic-tests',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),    
    'language' => 'en-US',
    'components' => [
        'db' => $dbParams,
        'mailer' => [
            'useFileTransport' => true, // <--- I'm interested in this setting 
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'showScriptName' => true,
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        ],        
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'test',
            'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
            // but if you absolutely need it set cookie domain to localhost
            /*
            'csrfCookie' => [
                'domain' => 'localhost',
            ],
            */
        ],        
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

I even thought that this path might be relative to /tests directory, so I created file there as well:

**/tests/config/test.php**

```
<?php
// config/test.php
$config =  yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/main-local.php'),
    [
        'id' => 'app-tests',
        'components' => [
            'db' => [
                'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii_app_test',
            ],
            'mailer' => [
                'useFileTransport' => true
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
return $config;
```

**/tests/_bootstrap.php**

```
<?php
define('YII_ENV', 'test');
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require __DIR__ .'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

**part of /config/web.php to check if environment values are passed, but they aren't**

```
if (YII_ENV_TEST || YII_ENV === 'test'){
    die('Testing settings loaded');
}
```

Launching my tests with `./vendor/bin/codecept run tests/acceptance/ContactCest.php`

I'm not publishing tests because they are irrelevant, as they just use clicks on elements to send contact form.
At the moment I've wasted 4 hours trying to override that config file. Probably it's some stupid rookie mistake, but I'm about to give up now.

*Help me, StackOverflow, you are my only hope! ;)*

Comment: Since `'useFileTransport' => true,` is true it shouldn't send emails?.. Maybe? Not sure. According to here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mail-basemailer.html#$useFileTransport-detail at least.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas yes, it shouldn't. But it sends, because value from my web.php config file isn't overriden.

Comment: Well, I can only suggest to create a copy of file and then make changes to the main file.

Comment: And how can I automate that, so it would be changed just for the test?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can automate the main file. :(

Comment: But it *should* be possible, it was documented here: http://codeception.com/for/yii#Manual-Setup--Configuration . The thing is - it's not working for me. So I'm doing something improperly, rather than it's impossible.

Comment: Well, in there it uses different file so it's not the same thing like I said before (automate the main file). I don't know how to set a different file. :/